# Python, text document to list?

Tags: python, list, text

In Python I'm trying to take a text document that has a bunch of words all separated by new lines, and select them one by one and edit them. How would I turn these items into a list in python?

Ex.

hi

I

need

help

That needs to be able to be put into a list in python so I can edit them, I'm trying to add the numbers 1-99 after every one.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1907538/python-import-a-file-and-convert-to-a-list

Comment: @movrev the code in that post shouldn't be used as an example. Most of the answers call `.readlines()` which is inefficient and also unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want to process the entire file as one large String (which may be very inefficient), you could use the splitlines() method like:

```
listOfWords = textFile.splitlines()
```

where `textFile` is a String which represents all of the text in the text document.

Answer (score 1):

```
with open('timer.py', 'r') as f:
    for num,line in enumerate(f):
        print line.rstrip(),num
```

To be clear: the `with` line opens the file for reading, and names the `file` object 'f'.  'f' can be iterated over in a `for` loop, as if it was a list.  `for x in f` produces one line in a variable named x for each iteration of the loop.

I used `enumerate` to pair each line with a line-number.

Also, I used `line.rstrip()` to remove the newline from the end of each line.

Answer (score 0):

I might suggest using an iterator instead; this will avoid storing the entire file in memory.

```
i = 0
for line in open('filename.txt'):
   print "{0} {1}".format(line, i)
   i += 1
```

Comment: Okay sounds good, sorry for asking such a silly question I just couldn't find any good sources on such things!

Comment: That's not a generator expression

Comment: ... whoops. Good call. I've corrected the answer.